# Как помогает время с анимацией?

Tags: c++, время, sfml

я начал изучать sfml c++ и там чтобы была плавная анимация нужно скорость умножать на время.

Внимание, вопрос!

ЗАЧЕМ?

вот пример кода:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800,300),"Game!"); //создание окна
    Event ev; //объект событий
    CircleShape circle(10.f,100.f); //создание круга
    circle.setFillColor(Color::Green); //тут все понятно

    Clock Timer; //Запускаем таймер, который я не понимаю зачем нужен
    float time;  //переменная для хранения времени


    while(window.isOpen())
    {

        while(window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if(ev.type==Event::Closed)window.close();
        }

        time = Timer.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds(); //Записываем туда время в миллисекундах
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            circle.move(2.f*time,0.f); //Вот В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ ВОПРОС
        }
        Timer.restart(); //перезапуск таймера

        window.clear();
        window.draw(circle);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем скорость умножать на время? И как это помогает? Разжуйте все плииз.

И да, у меня от этого только хуже стало, двигается не пропорционально, когда-то на чу-чуть, а когда-то на много, и получается типо лагов

Comment: Здесь `time` - это время, за которое был обработан предыдущий кадр. На него умножают, чтобы объекты двигались с одинаковой скоростью при любом FPS (а иначе чем больше FPS, тем быстрее было бы движение). Есть и другие, более удобные способы работать с изменяющимся FPS, см. https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

Comment: я все равно не понял, ведь если без этого, то у меня все лучше работает

Comment: Насколько лучше? Можете записать эти подергивания на гифку или видео?